# Redirect form to same url in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, post

I want to create a form in a symfony2 project that redirects to the same page after being processed. However I'm currently receiving always `NULL`  when reading the request `$parameters` whenever the form is being submitted.

The controller:

```
public function formAction(Request $request)
{
    $parameters = $request->request->all();
    var_dump($parameters);

    return array();
}
```

The twig template:

```
...
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
...
```

Comment: You should add a  `name` attribute to your  `input` field.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. May be you could write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `name` attribute to your `input` field:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
```